# Install Estimote SDK for Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, estimote

I am trying to integrate the Estimote SDK into an Android app. I am following the SDK instructions available at https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK. I have added the estimote-sdk-preview.jar file to the libs directory. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

**The Error message I receive are:**

- cannot resolve symbol 'estimote'
- cannot resolve symbol 'sdk'
- cannot resolve symbol 'service'
- cannot resolve symbol 'BeaconService'

**This is how I am trying to Add the Service**

```
<service android:name="com.estimote.sdk.service.BeaconService"
    android:exported="false"/>
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="company.com.application1" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        //----------THIS IS WHERE THE ERRORS ARE----------
        <service android:name="com.estimote.sdk.service.BeaconService"
        android:exported="false"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you using Eclispe or Android Studio?

Comment: @Hespen I'm using Android Studio. Thanks for the help!

Comment: How have you imported the .jar?  Did you just copied the jar to the lib folder? Or did you add it by using the AS functions? Did you add:     compile project(':estimote-sdk-preview') to your Gradle Build file?

Comment: I just used Finder on my mac to copy the jar to the libs directory. Is there something I need to do to instantiate it or something? Should I add it another way? I did not add compile project(':estimote-sdk-preview') to my Gradle Build file. I'm not sure where I would go to do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should go to File -> Project Structure -> Click the green +  -> Select 'Import .JAR or .AAR Package' from the 'More modules' list -> Select the JAR file.
Then go to your build.gradle file and add the following line to your dependencies block

```
compile project(':estimote-sdk-preview')
```